# CakePHP multiple layouts 1 backend

Tags: cakephp, web

I want to create a backend with CakePHP and I want to assign multiple designs to it. How am I going to do this?

For example: I want to create a blog system and use that backend in 5 different websites. I don't want to copy all backend (ofcourse).

Can someone give me advice in how te set this up?

Comment: CakePHP supports themes.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html

Comment: Ahh, shit, sorry! I overlooked it. I saw it, but I thought it would be more just other stylesheets or something.

Answer (score 0):

from a controller

```
public function admin_view() {
    // stuff
    $this->layout = 'admin';
}
```

from a view file

```
$this->layout = 'loggedin';
```